# FileOutputStream writing less than it should

Tags: java, file, file-io, fileoutputstream

I am trying to write a program that save into a .txt the data of a sinwave but when I execute the program it writes less (sometimes even nothing) that it should. Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GeneradorSeñal gs = new GeneradorSeñalSinusoidal("sgsg");
    Double salida;
    try{
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("out.txt"); 
        OutputStreamWriter muestras = new OutputStreamWriter(out);

        for(int i=0; i<500; i++){
            salida=gs.getSalida();
            muestras.write(String.valueOf(salida)+"\n");
            System.out.println(i+"\t"+salida);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
}
```

GeneradorSeñal and GeneradorSeñalSinusoidal are the classes that create the sinusoidal.
gs.getSalida() returns the value of the sinusoidal, the sinusoidal class works well, it is not the problem.

Comment: add `muestras.flush()` or `muestras.clos()` at the end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to *always* invoke the `close()` method of the output stream. This makes sure all buffered data are written to the stream.

Also if you're writing characters, it's more convenient to use a `FileWriter` instead.

Comment: When I add: finally{muestras.close(); }  I get an error.

Comment: @Cypert could you post the error that you get in the question?

Comment: @Cypert For your error, declare `OutputStreamWriter muestras` outside your try clause.

Answer (score 0):

I improved your code a bit:

```
... ...
try{
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("out.txt"); 
    OutputStreamWriter muestras = new OutputStreamWriter(out);

    for(int i=0; i<500; i++){
        salida=gs.getSalida();
        muestras.write(String.valueOf(salida)+"\n");
        System.out.println(i+"\t"+salida);
    }
    muestras.flush();
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    if(out!=null){
        try{out.close();}
        catch(Throwable e){
             e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Use finally to ensure the output stream is 100% closed.And use "out!=null" in case of out is not initialised. Close the 'out' instead of closing "muestras" in case of out is open but "muestras" is not.

Comment: I don not know if I shoul create a new question for this so I ask you, if I want to clase multiple files, how would I do it? I have multiple try catch and finally nested but I know that it does not reach every close. And thank you very much for your response.

Comment: Write a util class/method that accepts file name and file content you want to append as input parameters. Invoke that method for each file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
try{
 for(int i=0; i<500; i++){
        salida=gs.getSalida();
        muestras.write(String.valueOf(salida)+"\n");
        muestras.flush();
        System.out.println(i+"\t"+salida);
    }
}catch(IOException ioe){
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    try{
       muestras.close();
    }finally{}
}
```